# How to change a Cypress.on() call to a new function

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a `Cypress.on('window:load', (win) => {})` function that checks for any visible error banners and throws an error if it is visible. This is to catch any unexpected errors throughout the whole testing suite. I want to test for correct error messages in a few specific cases though and need a way to disable or overwrite the on('window:load') call on a test by test basis.

I have tried just setting it to an empty function that returns on the first line from within the test but it still runs the original command. I've also tried creating a flag to disable the function that checks for errors but the window:load function is loaded in before any test is run so it can't be changed on a test by test basis.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a handler use `Cypress.off()`.

But the handler must be declared as a separate function, and the same function reference passed to both `Cypress.on()` and `Cypress.off()`.

```js
function handler1() {
  .. handle the event
}

const eventName = 'window:load'

Cypress.on(eventName, handler1) 

.. some testing going on, catching the events for eventName

Cypress.off(eventName, handler1)   

.. some more testing, no longer catching the event
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable it without it being the same function reference? Say just removing all functions currently under the window:load event?

Comment: See [removeAllListeners](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/catalog-of-events#Binding-to-Events)